# How to set css value per operating system in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I know I know it is probably only a workaround but I am only a Wordpress amateur and currently need a quick solution, even if a dirty one...

My Wordpress site has a side bar. Unfortunately I have a problem where on android (and probably IOS as well - didn't check) the side bar takes almost half the width of the mobile screen, and in windows, on a pc\laptop screen it looks ok.
So, I narrowed in the custom CSS the sidebar width and now I've got the opposite problem. Looks find on mobile and bad on the PC monitor.

I am using Helium theme.

This is the css value I use to set the sidebar width:

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

I checked "Browser and Operating System Finder" plugin but failed to understand how to utilize if for my needs.

I guess the pros have better solution, but even a quick and dirty will be welcomed for now.

An example of the sidebar(filled with button widgets) overlapping the background items on PC screen:

[image: An example of the sidebar(filled with button widgets) overlapping the background items on PC screen]

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should probably look at css media queries. You should alter your css based on characteristics, not on device type

Comment: @TommyBs Thank you Tommy - it works! If you'd like to, you can answer the question and then I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be looking at determining what to display based on device, but rather on characteristics, and for this I would recommend css media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

This allows you to change css based on size and other factors e.g

```
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width:480px) {
     /* styles here */
}
```

You can even add things such as orientation

```
@media (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

The reason this is better than just looking for a specific device e.g iphone is that if Apple released a new iPhone that had an even bigger screen, your standard stylesheet might work, or it might not. Media queries will allow you greater flexibility going forward.